# Make localStorage Data read-Only

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am working on AngularJs application .

I store data in localStorage as

```
localStorageService.set("selectedUserCategory",'Circle');
```

Now When I see Browser's localStorage data

-- Application
  ---- LocalStorage

I find my `key-value` as

**selectedUserCategory : 'Circle'**

But this data is **editable** . i.e

If I edit data from `Circle` to `Ci` through browser itself it gets saved as `Ci`, and this might prove harmful because anyone can change data from there .
So I thought of making it **read-only** . Is there any way of doing it ?

Also is there any way to secure my localStorage data ?
Since the data is easily readable should I encrypt it and then save ??

Comment: Nothing stored locally can be trusted. If you want storage that the user can't edit, you'll need to store the data server side and send it to the user.

Answer (score 4):

As said by @Carcigenicate nothing is secure once it's on browser. One more step you can do is to store encrypted data in local storage. So it will be difficult for normal user to edit. And if he edits it will not decrypt and thus you can invalid following tasks.

To prevent further, you can Obfuscate/minify your javascript files so it's difficult for ordinary user to reach to your encryption algorithm.

Or if possible encrypt values from server, and using public key, only decryption logic will be on front end side. So even if user gets your data (**AND public key even**), he won't be able to encrypt it (without your private key) thus it makes impossible for him to alter data.

[JSON web token](https://jwt.io/) uses this principle, visit https://jwt.io/