# Where to store user information other than local storage in Angular 6 application and persist the same on reload?

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular6

In my Angular 6 Application have some data object which includes `user roles`.

Depending on the roles i `hide/show` the modules in the UI. I'm storing the user details in `localstorage`.

But, i dont want to expose the current user details and don't want to store the details in `localstorage` so that it can be edited to see the other modules.

Is their any way to keep the data so that it can't be edited and should persist on `page reloads` as well?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to store your detail with encryption so other user can not change.

Comment: In essence, all your "permission checks" are client side, and the "secret" data is also available client side, and client side code decides whether to hide or display it? … That's never going to be anywhere nearly secure. If there's something you do not want users to see, that *must* be enforced server-side so the secret data never even reaches the client's machine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make localStorage Data read-Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820693/make-localstorage-data-read-only)

Comment: I think this type of behavior should handle by backend logic. not front end.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [ngStore](https://github.com/ngrx/store)  which he can help you to edit the user data and know the previous content before the update.